# Web Service user authentication

Tags: c#, security, authorization, webservice-client

I'm trying to develop web service client with user authorization.
I've added service references to my project but now i've stuck on user authentication,
all i get is:

```
The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.
```

This is how i call my webservice:

```
BasicHttpBinding a = new BasicHttpBinding("MyWebService1");
a.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
a.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName;

MyWebService1Client mySeviceClient= new MyWebService1Client();
mySeviceClient= new MyWebService1Client(a, mySeviceClient.Endpoint.Address);

mySeviceClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "test2";
mySeviceClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";

try
{
    mySeviceClient.Open();
    MyWebService1 myWebService= mySeviceClient;
    myRequest req = new myRequest(1234, "Test");
    myResponse res = myWebService.getMyData(req);
    mySeviceClient.Close();
}
catch (AddressAccessDeniedException adExc)
{
           Console.WriteLine(adExc.Message);
           Console.ReadLine();
}
catch (System.Exception exc)
{
    Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

And here is my app.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="MyWebService1"/>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:7002/WSauth-WS_auth-context-root/MyWebService1Port"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyWebService1"
            contract="TestWs.MyWebService1" name="MyWebService1Port" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you comment out a.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly; and see what happens?

Comment: I get the same exeption. I've wrote client in java for this WS and everything was fine. The WS is deployed on WebLogic 10.3.6 and authorization is provided by it, maybe that is the matter?